# Different taxonomy_term view depending on vocabulary (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using taxonomy_term view to display term pages. The problem is that taxonomy_term view, when active, is used for every term page.

I need to display different term pages depending on the vocabulary that the term is assigned to.

If I have vocabulary "1", I need to display only image and title, when I have vocabulary "2" I need image, title and teaser. Finally, when using vocabulary "3", I need the same items as in vocab 2, but with different sort criteria.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a fairly simple way or at least a way to use taxonomy_term view for 2 vocabularies and use regular term pages for others? I searched on drupal.org, there are many similar questions, but usually the answer is that some other modules should be user (e.g. Panels), which is quite complicated and it affects speed performance. Here is a useful discussion, with a snippet, but it didn't work for me:

http://drupal.org/node/224231#comment-1981052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taxonomy Views Integrator module is exactly what you're looking for: http://drupal.org/project/tvi

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it's the thing I'm looking for! I'll play with it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for that Jared, I didn't know about that module.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add one more(how many variants you want) page display for the taxonomy listing.
2. In each of the display go to `Filter and select Taxonomy: Vocabulary` and then choose the vocabulary for you are creating this particular display.
3. `Change the fields` accordingly in each of the display.

This will create different URL for each of the taxonomy page of the display.
If you want all of them to have the same url then use attachment display and then attach all the displays to the basic page. And you are done :)

Comment: @Gokul-N-K Unfortunately, it isn't that simple. You can use only one page display for texonomy_term view, all of the others are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to Jared, this site lists some ways to do this via code:
http://www.appnovation.com/custom-taxonomy-term-pages

Basically, you're using `hook_menu_alter()` to look at the vocabulary name, then manually displaying a view of your choice.

This is a better option for D7, in my opinion, since the D7 version of TVI is not ready for production (according to the module page).